# How to make a batch file that writes directory names to a text file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that scans a directory of folders and outputs the names to a text file.

The folder names are as follows:

```
    Folder Name 1 [123abc]
    Folder Name 2 [abc321]
```

I'm needing the the folder names deleted leaving only the brackets and whats in between them listed out to a new.txt

Like this:

```
    [123abc]
    [abc321]
```

Comment: Please include the code you have tried so far, so we can help you debug or improve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=2delims=[]" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "yourdirectoryname\*[*]*" ') do echo [%%a]>>new.txt
```

(untested - batch line)

Perform a directory list in `/b` basic form, `/`ad` of directories only, selecting against the supplied mask in the directory nominated.

Process each line of this list, tokenise using `[` and `]` ,select the second token and assign to the metavariable `%%a`. Enclose that metavariable in brackets and output by appending to the file.

If run from the prompt, reduce each `%%a` to `%a`.

Comment: THANK YOU!  That's exactly what I was needing.